# How to remove password from SSIS project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

Have a simple task, but I just cannot find the quick work around, or maybe I just don't have all the info.
I have a solution (VS2012 Pro) for a SSIS project, which contains lots of dtsx packages.
When I first open the solution it pops up the enter password screen, which I want to get rid of, of course knowing the password.
My question is, is there necessary to get to the proprieties tab of each and every dtsx package and remove the password, or is there a "master setting" for the hole project? Or should I use an application which should remove the password from a command line?
Regards,

Comment: Which deployment model do you use? Package or project?

Comment: @Pred: I use the project model

Comment: Are your connections declared in package or in project level? If they are declared on project level, you have to set up the connection properties properly. SSIS pops up the password dialog when it can not connect to one of the data sources using the stored credentials.

Comment: Ohh and, you may want to set the ProtectionLevel if you are using passwords instead of kerberos. Please read this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918760

Comment: @Pred: ok, I get what you wrote, but I have like 25+ packages, therefore I should go to each and every one of them and set that property, from what is now (EncryptSensitiveWithPassword) to something else, like DontSaveSensitive?

Comment: Can't recall if there is a project level option (I have no SSDT/VS here to check). I recommend to change your authentication method to windows auth (if possible). Changing the Protection level is not the best practice and a potential security hole.

Comment: @Pred: I've checked and all connections have the authentication method to windows authentication. So my question is still the same: do I have to change the setting for the 25+ dtsx packages in order to get rid of the password screen when opening the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot packages to update, I would suggest you to write a script to do it in a batch.

what I did couple years ago, I created a c# project, process each ssis package, udpate pass word and then save the package. it works fine.

API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.aspx

example: https://github.com/guoliang-dev/ssis-utils/blob/master/SSISHelper/com/liguoliang/ssis/util/DtsUtils.cs

Answer (score 0):

I've just got rid of the annoying password, but the hard way. Although, the project had a security option setting, it notified me after changing it that I should manually check each and every package in order to match the security setting with the project one.